# Find value for a given key using grep in the string

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How can I grep SSID value from the string below using grep?

```
SSID: Home, BSSID: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

I tried

```
grep -oh "SSID:.*,"
```

and other combinations but to no avail.

The reluctant `?` quantifer using `-p` in `grep` is also not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
% grep -Po '(^|\s)SSID:\s\K[^,]+' file.txt
```

Example:

```
% grep -Po '(^|\s)SSID:\s\K[^,]+' <<<'SSID: Home, BSSID: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'
Home
```

Comment: -P isnt working on OSX terminal. so not able to test it. Do you have alternative for OSX